# How to append the last record of each change in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I am a newbie to Scala and currently what I am doing is to filter the data from a big data set and print them as csv. So the csv I print in this format:

```
id         time                              status
___        _____                            _________
1        2016-10-09 00:09:10                    100
1        2016-10-09 00:09:30                    100
1        2016-10-09 00:09:50                    100
1        2016-10-09 00:10:10                    900
2        2016-10-09 00:09:18                    100
2        2016-10-09 00:09:20                    100
2        2016-10-09 00:10:24                    900
3        2016-10-09 00:09:30                    100
3        2016-10-09 00:09:33                    100
3        2016-10-09 00:09:36                    100
3        2016-10-09 00:09:39                    100
3        2016-10-09 00:09:51                    900
```

I am using the below code to print the data:

```
      var count=0;

      val StatusList = ListBuffer[String]();
       for (currentRow <- sortedRow) {
              if (currentRow.status==100){
                   StatusList.+=(currentRow.id+","+currentRow.time+","+currentRow.status)
                }
              if((count+1) <  sortedRow.size && sortedRow(count+1).status==900)   {
                   StatusList.+=(sortedRow(count+1).id+","+sortedRow(count+1).time+","+sortedRow(count+1).status)
                }
     count+=1;

    }
```

Instead of this I want to print the rows with status 100 and append the record when they changed. Basically I want to print the data as follows:

```
 id       time                status    id     change_time         status
___      _____               _________  __    ______________       _______
1    2016-10-09 00:09:10      100       1      2016-10-09 00:10:10    900
1    2016-10-09 00:09:30      100       1      2016-10-09 00:10:10    900
1    2016-10-09 00:09:50      100       1      2016-10-09 00:10:10    900
2    2016-10-09 00:09:18      100       2      2016-10-09 00:10:24    900
2    2016-10-09 00:09:20      100       2      2016-10-09 00:10:24    900
3    2016-10-09 00:09:30      100       3      2016-10-09 00:09:51    900
3    2016-10-09 00:09:33      100       3      2016-10-09 00:09:51    900
3    2016-10-09 00:09:36      100       3      2016-10-09 00:09:51    900
3    2016-10-09 00:09:39      100       3      2016-10-09 00:09:51    900
```

Comment: You can separate the two status into two csvs but what are the rules of appending? append randomly or are there some strict rules for appending?

Comment: I can seperate but for further analysis I need to keep in the above format

Comment: You didn't read my question carefully. I asked what is the rule for the combination?

Comment: Actually the whole data is a sequence of where status is 100 and first change  to 900(for each id).So I need to append the first change of 100 to 900 grouped by each id.

Comment: Exactly this is the expected output.Sorry for the misleading output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146822/discussion-between-ramesh-maharjan-and-ricky).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am suggesting you solution using `dataframes` which is an optimized and improved works done for `RDD`s.

I am assuming that the data is in following format with header line

```
id,time,status
1,2016-10-0900:09:10,100
1,2016-10-0900:09:30,100
1,2016-10-0900:09:50,100
1,2016-10-0900:10:10,900
```

First step would be to read the files into `dataframe` using `sqlContext`

```
 val sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext
 val dataframe = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("absolute path to the input file")
```

You should have `dataframe` as

```
+---+------------------+------+
|id |time              |status|
+---+------------------+------+
|1  |2016-10-0900:09:10|100   |
|1  |2016-10-0900:09:30|100   |
|1  |2016-10-0900:09:50|100   |
|1  |2016-10-0900:10:10|900   |
|2  |2016-10-0900:09:18|100   |
|2  |2016-10-0900:09:20|100   |
|2  |2016-10-0900:10:24|900   |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:30|100   |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:33|100   |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:36|100   |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:39|100   |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:51|900   |
+---+------------------+------+
```

Next step would be to filter the `dataframe` into two with `status` difference

```
val df1 = dataframe.filter(dataframe("status") === "100")
```

Output is as

```
+---+------------------+------+
|id |time              |status|
+---+------------------+------+
|1  |2016-10-0900:09:10|100   |
|1  |2016-10-0900:09:30|100   |
|1  |2016-10-0900:09:50|100   |
|2  |2016-10-0900:09:18|100   |
|2  |2016-10-0900:09:20|100   |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:30|100   |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:33|100   |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:36|100   |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:39|100   |
+---+------------------+------+
```

follow the same for `900` status for `df2` but with `column` names renamed

```
val df2 = dataframe.filter(dataframe("status") === "900")
  .withColumnRenamed("id", "id2")
  .withColumnRenamed("time", "changed_time")
  .withColumnRenamed("status", "status2")
```

Output should be

```
+---+------------------+-------+
|id2|changed_time      |status2|
+---+------------------+-------+
|1  |2016-10-0900:10:10|900    |
|2  |2016-10-0900:10:24|900    |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:51|900    |
+---+------------------+-------+
```

Final step is `join` those two `dataframes`

```
val finalDF = df1.join(df2, df1("id") === df2("id2"), "left")
```

final output is as

```
+---+------------------+------+---+------------------+-------+
|id |time              |status|id2|changed_time      |status2|
+---+------------------+------+---+------------------+-------+
|1  |2016-10-0900:09:10|100   |1  |2016-10-0900:10:10|900    |
|1  |2016-10-0900:09:30|100   |1  |2016-10-0900:10:10|900    |
|1  |2016-10-0900:09:50|100   |1  |2016-10-0900:10:10|900    |
|2  |2016-10-0900:09:18|100   |2  |2016-10-0900:10:24|900    |
|2  |2016-10-0900:09:20|100   |2  |2016-10-0900:10:24|900    |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:30|100   |3  |2016-10-0900:09:51|900    |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:33|100   |3  |2016-10-0900:09:51|900    |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:36|100   |3  |2016-10-0900:09:51|900    |
|3  |2016-10-0900:09:39|100   |3  |2016-10-0900:09:51|900    |
+---+------------------+------+---+------------------+-------+
```

Saving the final `dataframe` to `csv` file is quite easy as well

```
finalDF.write.format("csv").save("absolute path to output filename ")
```